What is the best scientific calculator to solve or balance the accounting task?
For accounting tasks, the best scientific calculator needs to offer a mix of basic arithmetic functions, financial functions, and the ability to perform complex calculations

IMHO speedcrunch is best calculator ever for science and accounting.  In the view settings click on "history" and its great for finances as you can see everything you typed in.  For science, in the view setttings click on the "formula book, or variables, etc....  Lot's of options.  You can also choose a dark or light theme.  In the terminal.....
sudo apt install speedcrunch

And then look for it in your accessories.
